# Extending base class fields functionality

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, derived-class

I have next code that represents graph edges and nodes (simplified for question):

```
public class Node
{
}

public class Edge
{
    public Node Source { get; set; }
    public Node Target { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to extend this classes for describing mine topology:

```
public class MineNode : Node
{
    public double FanPressure { get; set; }
}

public class MineTunnel : Edge
{
    public double Length { get; set; }
    public double CrossSectionArea { get; set; }

    public MineTunnel()
    {
        Source = new MineNode();
        Target = new MineNode();
    }
}
```

The problem is that I want to access additional data provided by `MineNode` when using `Source` and `Target` properties, but I can access only `Node` fields because they are declared in base class:

```
MineTunnel t = new MineTunnel();
Console.WriteLine(t.Source.FanPressure); //Error
```

The only way to access `FanPressure` is to cast `Source` to `MineNode` but code become ugly this way.

```
Console.WriteLine(((MineNode)t.Source).FanPressure); //OK
```

The another way is maybe to use somehow generics in base class declaration. But I'm not sure is that a good practice in my situation.

So, how can I solve such problem - extend functionality of base class fields?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think generics is the way to go here...

Try this:

```
public class Node
{

}

public class Edge<S, T>
    where S : Node
    where T : Node
{
    public S Source { get; set; }
    public T Target { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can extend the Node and Edge classes with:

```
public class MineNode : Node
{
    public double FanPressure { get; set; }
}

public class MineTunnel : Edge<MineNode, MineNode>
{
    public double Length { get; set; }
    public double CrossSectionArea { get; set; }

    public MineTunnel()
    {
        Source = new MineNode();
        Target = new MineNode();
    }
}
```

Please correct me if this is wrong or doesn't work... :)

```
MineTunnel t = new MineTunnel();
Console.WriteLine(t.Source.FanPressure); // Now this works without errors ;)
```

Comment: Why do you have Edge extending Node?

Comment: Oh sorry, that wasn't intentional. Guess it slipped in there when i was writing the class header

Comment: Why do source and target node have different types?

Comment: Because I thought it would be possible for an Edge to go from i.e MineNode to YourNode. You could specify different types for source and target.

Comment: Different generic types its OK, but I will use always the same anyway. All answers are good and correct but you was a little bit faster.

Answer (score 6):

You could define your `Edge` type as generic, with constraints:

```
public class Edge<TNode> where TNode: Node
{
  public TNode Source { get; set; }
  public TNode Target { get; set; }
}
```

Through which you could redefine your `MineTunnel` type as:

```
public class MineTunnel : Edge<MineNode>
{
  // Stuff
}
```